# VertScrollBar.Visible always returns TRUE

Tags: delphi

I have a custom control derived from TScrollBox. At run time, I need to know weather the vertical scrollbar is visible or not. If I interrogate the Visible property it always returns true, no matter if the scrollbar is visible or not!

```
function TMyScrollPanel.ScrollVisible: boolean;
begin
 Result:=  Self.VertScrollBar.Visible;            <----------- always true
end;
```

However, this works correctly:

```
function VertScrollBarVisible(WindowHandle: THandle): Boolean;                  
begin
 Result:= (GetWindowlong(WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE) AND WS_VSCROLL) <> 0
end;
```

What is wrong with the first function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Reading a scrollbar `Visible` property only retrives VCL control state. The property won't retrieve the current state from the actual scrollbar window. Use the `IsScrollBarVisible` property instead.</strike>

Use the `IsScrollBarVisible` method instead, to check whether a scrollbar is visible because the scrollable window can be scrolled.

Reading the `Visible` property only retrieves the cached value of its visibility setting (can be visible or not). For a scrollable window, the property won't retrieve the current state from the actual window.

Comment: So, I guess the name of the property should be 'VertScrollBar.NeverShow' instead of 'VertScrollBar.Visible' :)

Comment: @Altar, better would be `VertScrollBar.CanShow` ;-)

Comment: @Jay, could you correct your answer, please ? Scrollbars aren't VCL controls actually...

Comment: @Jay, you can update it this way *<strike>Reading a scrollbar Visible property only retrives VCL control state. The property won't retrieve the current state from the actual scrollbar window. Use the IsScrollBarVisible property instead.</strike> Use the IsScrollBarVisible function instead.*...

Comment: Actually it is not a property, but a function.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Oops, missed that. Thanks.